# MongoError: cursor is dead (mongo node driver)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I am using node-mongodb-native 2.0 http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/

With the following Node.js code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongoUrl = 'mongodb://localhost/twitter';

MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, db) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);

  var collection = db.collection('tweets');

  collection.find().limit(1000).forEach(function(tweet) {
    console.log(tweet.id);
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    db.close();
  });
});
```

When I set the limit to `1000` (`collection.find().limit(1000)`), I was able to retrieve first several hundreds records, but I got error message `{ [MongoError: cursor is dead] name: 'MongoError', message: 'cursor is dead' }` later on (I got 1 million records in my collection). But the program runs OK we I specify `800` as limit. It's also OK to not specify any limit (just `collection.find()`), and the script just keeps going without any error (reading way more records than 1000).

#### What's wrong? How to solve? How to solve if I still want to use `forEach` on a cursor?

Comment: quick question - how long does the 800 limit option take to run (approximately)?

Comment: @AdamComerford Feels like a second.

Comment: OK, so not likely hitting a timeout then. I just tried to reproduce (straight copy and paste of your code using a test database with ~500k documents) and get no error, tried a limit of 2000, 20000, 100k too - still no problem.  Are the documents particularly large? You could try only returning id using a projection: `collection.find({}, {"_id" : 0, id : 1})` - if you then indexed the id field it would be a covered index query.

Comment: @AdamComerford if I use `collection.find({}, {"_id" : 0, id : 1})`, I retrieved 1000 records successfully. I run a `db.stats()` and the `avgObjSize` is 6954.4177304430095.

Comment: OK, I have now reproduced it and can seemingly do it at will every time with my test data.  I'll see if this is a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have [reproduced this issue](https://gist.github.com/comerford/da8c8c0eeaae4e134d23) with a sample data set of smaller documents.  The telling part is likely this log line from MongoDB:

```
2014-10-21T18:50:32.548+0100 [conn50] query twitter.tweets planSummary: COLLSCAN cursorid:30362014860 ntoreturn:200000 ntoskip:0 nscanned:199728 nscannedObjects:199728 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) r:120400 nreturned:199728 reslen:4194308 120ms
```

The key piece, I suspect is `reslen:4194308` which looks suspiciously close to the default batch size of 4MiB.  I've been in touch with the node.js driver developers, will let you know if this ends up as a bug (update: opened [NODE-300](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-300), and confirmed fix in `mongodb-core@1.0.4` as result).

In the meantime, I'd recommend using the workaround from the comments, namely using a projection to reduce the amount of data in the results and sidestepping the issue.

**Updated Resolution:** If you are seeing this (or a similar) issue, then please update your `mongodb-core` version and retry - the new version no longer errors and runs quite a bit faster also.  I did this by removing my node_modules and re-running `npm install` for my test app.

Comment: I saw the version changes https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE/fixforversion/14495 thanks